# How to associated two classes when "customer has tickets"

Tags: c#, oop

I have a basic OOP question.  Say for instance I have a customer that has either one or more tickets.  So, I want to create a customer class that has one or more tickets.  Should I put a list of tickets property in the customer class?  Would the following be the best way of implementing this?  Would you recommend something different to keep with the SOLID?

```
public class Customer
{
   public string name { get; set; }
   public string address{ get; set; }
   public List<Ticket> ticket { get; set; } 
   ....
}

public class Ticket
{
    public int ticketno { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Are `Tickets` at the heart of your application?  Or are they one possible association?  If it's not a widely-used association then a `GetTicketsForCustomer` method on your repository may be a better choice.

Answer (score 2):

Seems reasonable to me.  I depends on how you want to use the data.  If for a particular Customer, you want all Tickets for that Customer, then this will work fine.  If you have a particular Ticket and want to find the customer that it belongs to, that will require some searching given these definitions.  In Ticket, you may also want to have a Customer, to quickly find the Customer the Ticket belongs to.  If a Ticket can belong to many Customers, then have a list of Customers in Ticket.

Comment: If I wanted to it to go both ways then maybe i could add a Customer property to my Ticket class.

  public class Customer
    {
       public string name { get; set; }
       public string address{ get; set; }
       public List<Ticket> ticket { get; set; } 
       ....
    }

    public class Ticket
    {
        public Customer customer { get; set;}
        public int ticketno { get; set; }
    }

Answer (score 0):

It is a proper way, You can have all ticket related details in ticket class and it is associated with a user so that we 1-to-Many relation...